# Auth0 as SP: React app receives a SAML response instead the redirect with code and state params

Tags: reactjs, saml, auth0, service-provider

We implemented Auth0 as Service Provider, like this [url](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-sp-generic)
In React we are using this [library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js).

After login success, in the react app we are receiving a POST with the SAML response, instead of POST redirect with `code` and `state` params, that the library uses to authenticate the user.

So my question is, The React app should handle the SAML response? if so, it's needed a node server to do this.

The Auth0 should handle the SAML response and redirect to the application with the above params? what configuration it's left to implement.

Comment: React is a view-layer that runs on the client; since it is not a server and has no built-in functionality for listening for HTTP requests, it cannot possibly receive an HTTP POST request from a third-party. Please update your question to be more specific about what is happening and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yes, I know. My main question is if I can implement the login with Auth0 as Service Provider but only React.

Answer (score 1):

SPA uses OpenID Connect and that should return the code etc.

However, the Auth0 example is for SAML.

You should configure an Auth0 [OpenID Connect connector](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/oidc) instead.

Comment: In "IdP-Initiated SSO" tab I changed the setting "Response Protocol" from "saml" to "OpenID Connect".
But, now I get only the code param, http://localhost:3000/?code=CiGDc8bMzSH356yY and in the console, I see this error "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid state". The state param is missing.

Comment: No - don't change the existing connection. Make a new connection as above.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the help, but I'm stuck with configuration. So, I should have one application in the "Applications" tab and two enterprise connections one in "Saml" and the other in "Open Id Connect", right? so how connect the openId connection with the app?

Comment: Remove the SAML connection and connect the application to OpenId Connect via https://auth0.com/docs/dashboard/guides/connections/enable-connections-enterprise